# How to implement multiselectable facet checkboxes with amazon cloudsearch?

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I am using amazon cloud search in my website.My website is an e learning portal where i have content of types videos,questions,courses etc.Each type of content having different levels like 1st grade,2nd grade,3rd grade etc of different curriculum like cbse,state board etc and of different educators like xyz,abc,pqr etc.I am filtering my content based on facet and also filtering facet based on facet selection.My filter is working like amazon cloudsearch console.In console we can not do multiple selection.My problem is that when i select one faceted checkbox then page loads and hides other filter options.I want to keep open all facets to perform multiple checkbox filter.Please help how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 'OR' the facet selections together. For example:

```
q=algebra&fq=(and (or grade:1 grade:2) (or educator:abc educator:xyz))&facet.grade={}&facet.educator={}&facet.curriculum={}
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/faceting.html

Comment: @alexrossos Thanks for your suggestions.I have "type" facet where type like videos courses and questions.But videos and courses are linked to some educator whereas question is not.I want while user selects questions then educator facet list should not appear.How to do this ?please suggest me.I want just like flipkart multiselect filter.

Comment: In that case, you would need to selectively add/remove the educator facet from your request (the facet.educator={} param).