# Multi-Select faceting on Amazon Cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

On Amazon cloudsearch how can I perform Multi-Select Faceting similar to that in [Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams)? In Solr we can use {!ex} so the GUI still displays all facets values with their associated counts, I want to achieve same but using Amazon cloudsearch.

Explanation of what is required:

Suppose there is a filter for doctypes, if someone wants to select pdf then other doctypes will return 0 count and thus will not get displayed on GUI, but I want to display all facets in order to select multiple doctypes.

```
=== Document Type ===
    [ ] Word (42)
    [x] PDF  (96)
    [ ] Excel(11)
    [ ] HTML (63)
```

1. I want to show all facet values along with their counts, even if the filter is active, so that I can select multiple.
2. In my filter box I am having three facets which should behave same as above explanation, and other filters should work as usual.

I have gone through documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/faceting.html) but was not able to find the solution. Any would be greatly appreciated.

---

My question is more or less similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279012/how-to-implement-multiselectable-facet-checkboxes-with-amazon-cloudsearch). I would have asked my doubt in comments there but I am not having enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question is answered in the AWS docs you linked to (quoted below). Basically you need to make 2 separate requests, one for the search query (which includes the selected facets) and another without any facet selections (to get all the values irrespective of selections). If there are other facets aside from Doc Type, you'd still want to submit those; you could conceivably end up making n requests to get facet data for your n facets (each request omitting one of the selected facet types in order to get the possible values for that facet). I can walk through an example if that doesn't make sense.

> If you want to display the available facets and enable users to select
>   multiple values to refine the results, you can submit one request to
>   get the documents that match the facet constraints and additional
>   requests to get the facet counts.

I'm not really sure what you're asking in the second part of your question since that is pretty much what is described in the question you linked to. If you can explain what specifically isn't working for you, I can try to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to provide answer, really appreciated.
I was asking I am having three facets which should work as multi-select, so am I supposed to send three separate queries in order to have facet counts and values, and for other facets which are not multi-select do I again have to send separate queries for those facets?
But I tried, it worked fine.
Is this the only way we could get multi-select facets working?

Comment: It does seem inefficient to make so many calls, but I believe this is the only way. Of course you only have to do it for the facets where the user has selected a value; all the facets with no selection can be retrieved by your main query (the one that actually gets the search results). I suppose the fact that most users probably never select a facet cuts down on the inefficiency a bit.